# CRUD <h:datatable> containing <h:inputText> in each row

Tags: java, jsf, dao

**This is the xhtml page**

[image: screenshot]

**This is the code:**

```
<h:form rendered="#{not empty utilisateurs.users}">
<h:dataTable var="item" value="#{utilisateurs.users}" border="1">
<h:column><f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet><h:inputText value="#{item.id}" binding="#{utilisateurs.inputId}"></h:inputText></h:column>
<h:column><f:facet name="header">Nom</f:facet><h:inputText value="#{item.nom}" binding="#{utilisateurs.inputName}"></h:inputText></h:column>
<h:column><f:facet name="header">email</f:facet><h:inputText value="#{item.email}" binding="#{utilisateurs.inputEmail}"></h:inputText></h:column>
<h:column><f:facet name="header">mot de passe</f:facet><h:inputText value="#{item.motDePasse}" binding="#{utilisateurs.inputPass}"></h:inputText></h:column>
<h:column><h:commandButton value="edit" action="#{utilisateurs.update()}" /></h:column>
<h:column><h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{utilisateurs.delete(item)}" /></h:column>
<h:column><h:commandButton value="save" action="#{utilisateurs.save(item)}" /></h:column>
```

**This is the managed bean:**

```
@ManagedBean(name="utilisateurs")
@ViewScoped
public class Users {
private HtmlInputText inputId=new HtmlInputText();
private HtmlInputText inputName=new HtmlInputText();
private HtmlInputText inputEmail=new HtmlInputText();
private HtmlInputText inputPass=new HtmlInputText();
private List<Utilisateur>users;
private UtilisateurDaoImpl dao;
private DAOFactory daoFactory;
private Utilisateur user=new Utilisateur();
private Utilisateur newUser=new Utilisateur();
public Utilisateur getNewUser() {
    return newUser;
}

public void setNewUser(Utilisateur newUser) {
    this.newUser = newUser;
}

private boolean edit;
 @PostConstruct
 public void init(){
    daoFactory=DAOFactory.getInstance();
    dao=new UtilisateurDaoImpl(daoFactory);
    users=new ArrayList<Utilisateur>();
    users=dao.lister(); 
    inputId.setDisabled(true);
    inputName.setDisabled(true);
    inputEmail.setDisabled(true);
    inputPass.setDisabled(true);
 }

public void setNewUser(Utilisateur newUser) {
    this.newUser = newUser;
}

private boolean edit;
 @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    daoFactory=DAOFactory.getInstance();
    dao=new UtilisateurDaoImpl(daoFactory);
    users=new ArrayList<Utilisateur>();
    users=dao.lister(); 

 }
public void add() {
dao.creer(user);
users.add(user);
user = new Utilisateur();
}

public void update() {
inputId.setDisabled(false);
inputName.setDisabled(false);
inputEmail.setDisabled(false);
inputPass.setDisabled(false);
}
public void save(Utilisateur user){
dao.update(user);
inputId.setDisabled(true);
inputName.setDisabled(true);
inputEmail.setDisabled(true);
inputPass.setDisabled(true);
}

public void delete(Utilisateur user) {
dao.delete(user);
users.remove(user);
}
```

The problem is that when I click on edit the whole datatable inputs gets enabled but I just want to enable the current line that I'm editing

Also if you could help I want to add only one row at the end of datatable so I can be able to insert some data too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are **binding the same UIComponet to all rows**. You need to change this.

I recommend you that take a look to this: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Is not mandatory to use primefaces or other lib, just use the idea.

For example, you can add a **boolean** attribute to your `Utilisateur` class, to enable/disable the row by clicking on a button 'edit'

```
public class Utilisateur {
   //... other code

   public boolean editMode;
   // getter and setter
}
```

In each row (replace binding in all inputs):

```
<h:inputText value="#{item.id}" readonly="#{!item.editMode}"></h:inputText>
```

And edit button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Make editable" actionListener="#{utilisateurs.editable(item)}" />
```

In your bean:

```
public void editable(Utilisateur user) {
   for(Utilisateur utilisateur : users) {
       utilisateur.setEditMode(false);
   }
   user.setEditMode(true);
}
```

Comment: can i do it whithout using the ajax ? can u explain more how to enable or disable the row using boolean?